# Merging observable sequences when types derive from the same interface

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a situation where I want to merge two observable sequences. The sequence consists of Messages like in Ex1 in the code example. I don't understand why it doesn't compile, when Ex2 compiles and runs as expected.

Can anyone explain this to me?

```
class Message<T> where T : IFoo {}
interface IFoo {}
class Foo : IFoo {}
class Bar : IFoo {}

class Program
{
    static void Ex1()
    {
        var o1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => new Message<Foo>());
        var o2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => new Message<Bar>());

        o1.Merge<Message<IFoo>>(o2).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Ex2()
    {
        var o1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => new Foo());
        var o2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => new Bar());

        o1.Merge<IFoo>(o2).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Error in Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Framework 4.6.1:

```
Error   CS1929  'IObservable<Message<Foo>>' does not contain a definition for 'Merge' and the best extension method overload 'Observable.Merge<Message<IFoo>>(IObservable<IObservable<Message<IFoo>>>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'IObservable<IObservable<Message<IFoo>>>'
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because `Foo` is derived from `IFoo` it does not mean that `Message<Foo>` derives from `Message<IFoo>` - **it does not** - so you can not cast it like you have. The same applies to `Bar` and `IBar`.

Comment: You've asked the question very well. You've given a great [mcve] and a clear example of what worked and what didn't, along with a clear error message. I'm impressed. Did you have a more concrete situation that you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because `Foo` is derived from `IFoo` it does not mean that `Message<Foo>` derives from `Message<IFoo>` - **it does not** - so you can not cast it like you have. The same applies to `Bar` and `IBar`.

Let's see why.

Instead of thinking in terms of `Message<T>`, let's use `List<T>`. I now have this code:

```
var foos = new List<Foo>();

foos.Add(new Foo());
foos.Add(new Foo());
```

That's good.

Now, like your question, when you try to change a `Message<Foo>` into a `Message<IFoo>`, let's try changing this to a `List<IFoo>`:

```
List<IFoo> ifoos = (List<IFoo>)foos; // Does not compile
```

Let's say that it did compile - for the sake of explaining why your code didn't work - so I would then have a `ifoos` that I could do this with:

```
ifoos.Add(new Bar());
```

After all, the reference I have for `ifoos` is of type `List<IFoo>` and `Bar` derives from `IFoo` so that would be perfectly valid code.

But `ifoos` is just a cast of `List<Foo>` and casting an object doesn't change its underlying type. A `List<Foo>` can only accept elements that are of type `Foo` (or derived from `Foo`). Now, given our magic change to the compiler, we've created a situation that it can accept `Bar`.

Boom! Run-time error.

That should clearly be why the cast `(List<IFoo>)foos` should fail. And that's why the cast `(Message<IFoo>)Message<Foo>` also fails in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the superb answer. The example made everything crystal clear. What I need is an IMessage interface!

Answer (score 1):

We'll start with why the second method works.

The second method creates two collections of type `Foo` and `Bar`. But in the `Merge` method the type to use is explicitly the interface `IFoo`. This tells the method that this is the type of objects to store in the new collection: `IEnumerable<IFoo>`. The collection accepts items of type `IFoo`, and since `Foo` and `Bar` both inherit from the interface they're accepted by the collection. If you were to remove the type parameter from the `Merge` method, or specify explicitly `Foo` or `Bar` as the type you would have the same error as the first method.

So what about the first method?

The first collection is of type `Message<Foo>`. The generic type for this `Message` is `Foo`. Note that this is not the same as `Message<IFoo>`, because the type is explicitly `Foo`, not its superclasses or interfaces. Similarly `Message<Bar>` has a generic type of `Bar`, not `IFoo`.

When the compiler comes to the `Merge` method with two collections (one of `Message<Foo>` and `Message<Bar>`) it knows that the generic types of the two `Messages` are not the same (a `Foo` is an `IFoo` and an `Bar` is an `IFoo`, but a `Foo` is not a `Bar`, and vice versa). So the compiler gives an error saying that it expects a collection of a related type (`requires a receiver of type 'IObservable<IObservable<Message<IFoo>>>'`).

There's one final thing to be aware of.

The definition of the `Message` class is `class Message<T> where T : IFoo {}`. All the `where` clause means means is that `T` must be an `IFoo` and that's it. It does not mean that a `Message<Foo>` is a `Message<IFoo>`. You can cast from a `Foo` to an `IFoo` and that's what happens in the second method, but they are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for spending time replying. I accepted Enigmativity's answer because of his excellent example.

Comment: Glad you got sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers here:

```
interface IMessage<out T> where T : IFoo { }
class Message<T> : IMessage<T> where T:IFoo { }
interface IFoo { }
class Foo : IFoo { }
class Bar : IFoo { }

class Program
{
    static void Ex1()
    {
        var o1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => (IMessage<IFoo>)new Message<Foo>());
        var o2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => (IMessage<IFoo>)new Message<Bar>());

        o1.Merge(o2).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ex1();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to read up on covariance and contravariance in generic type parameters. It's nice how you can get polymorphism like behaviour with generic types. It makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @DoubleTrouble Immutable types and Rx seem to play well. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/12/06/immutability-in-c-part-three-a-covariant-immutable-stack/